# How to auto login other tab when one tab is logged in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

When I log in to the one tab, I need to login other tabs at the same time in reacjs.

Comment: To improve this question quality i will recommend to add some auto refresh examples. Basically if other tabs have different "sessionId", you can send a websocket, or do long poll in every tab for check status log. But first describe your question more precisely

Answer (score 2):

If you:

- set your auth data to localstorage
- add an event listener on tab/window focus that check localstorage
- in that listener you update you Redux/Local state

..you're done.